# error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element in Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have upgraded angular version from 5 to 12 and It giving error `error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element`

I have lot of searched about this and did not worked for me.

Also giving the errors of **Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'**.I have upgraded all package to latest and still not working. Also some third party module is not working like : **pdf-viewer**

Thanks in Advance.

My **app.routing.module.ts** :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import {CanActivate} from "@angular/router";
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '',redirectTo: 'header-one-layout' ,pathMatch:'full'},
    { path: 'header-one-layout', loadChildren: () => import('./header-one-layout/header-one-layout.module').then(m => m.HeaderOneLayoutModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'header-two-layout', loadChildren: () => import('./header-two-layout/header-two-layout.module').then(m => m.HeaderTwoLayoutModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'header-three-layout', loadChildren: () => import('./header-three-layout/header-three-layout.module').then(m => m.HeaderThreeLayoutModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'header-four-layout', loadChildren: () => import('./header-four-layout/header-four-layout.module').then(m => m.HeaderFourLayoutModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'header-five-layout', loadChildren: () => import('./header-five-layout/header-five-layout.module').then(m => m.HeaderFiveLayoutModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'header-six-layout', loadChildren: () => import('./header-six-layout/header-six-layout.module').then(m => m.HeaderSixLayoutModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'all-prescription/:params', loadChildren: () => import('./confirmation-popup/all-prescription/all-prescription.module').then(m => m.AllPrescriptionModule),canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'user-can-view-prescription/:params', loadChildren: () => import('./print-prescription/print-prescription.module').then(m => m.PrintPrescriptionModule) },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My **app.module.ts** :

```
import { NgModule ,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { CountdownTimerModule } from 'ngx-countdown-timer';
import { ScrollToModule } from 'ng2-scroll-to-el';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { FormsModule,FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';
import {ConfirmationDialogComponent} from './confirmation-popup/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component'
import {ConfirmationDialogUpdateComponent} from './confirmation-popup/confirmation-dialog-update/confirmation-dialog-update.component';
import {CustomDialogComponent} from './confirmation-popup/custom-dialog/custom-dialog.component';
import { UiSwitchModule } from 'ngx-toggle-switch';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { AllPrescriptionComponent } from './confirmation-popup/all-prescription/all-prescription.component';
import { PinchZoomModule } from 'ngx-pinch-zoom';

import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PdfViewerModule } from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';
// import { NgbdTooltipDelay } from './tooltip-delay';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogUpdateComponent,
    CustomDialogComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PinchZoomModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      preventDuplicates: true,
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    CountdownTimerModule.forRoot(),
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.googleApiKey,
      libraries: ["places"]
    }),
    ScrollToModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    PdfViewerModule,
    UiSwitchModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents:[ConfirmationDialogComponent,ConfirmationDialogUpdateComponent,CustomDialogComponent] ,
   schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My **Package.json** :

```
  "name": "doctm",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --buildOptimizer --commonChunk --vendorChunk --optimization --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/translate": "^2.1.2",
    "@google/maps": "^0.4.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^12.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^1.0.0",
    "@rxjs/rx": "^4.1.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-confirmation-popover": "^4.2.1",
    "angular-material-badge": "^1.2.9",
    "angular-save-html-to-pdf": "^1.3.2",
    "angular2-datetimepicker": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-google-place": "^2.0.2",
    "angular4-fusioncharts": "^1.0.0",
    "angular5-csv": "^0.2.9",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "ckeditor": "^4.11.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "country-state-city": "0.0.5",
    "d3": "^5.7.0",
    "fullcalendar": "^3.7.0",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.12.2",
    "google-maps": "^3.3.0",
    "google-maps-api-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "googlemaps": "^1.12.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^2.3.5",
    "mouse-wheel-zoom": "^1.1.5",
    "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.7.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^7.0.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.3.0",
    "ng-selectize": "^1.1.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.2",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-material-dropdown": "^0.11.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^3.0.2",
    "ng2-scroll-to": "^1.0.7",
    "ng2-scroll-to-el": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-simple-timer": "^1.3.3",
    "ng4-auto-complete": "^1.0.0",
    "ngx-bar-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.2.2",
    "ngx-countdown-timer": "^0.1.9",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-papaparse": "^4.0.4",
    "ngx-pinch-zoom": "^2.4.4",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-stars": "^1.2.0",
    "ngx-tinymce": "^7.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.2.0",
    "plyr": "^3.5.4",
    "print-this": "^1.14.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "selectize": "^0.12.6",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.14.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "wheelzoom": "^4.0.1",
    "wheelzoom.js": "^1.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.27",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: In the module where you use `<router-outlet>`, did you import `RouterModule`?

Comment: Yes, I already imported on `app.routing.module.ts`

Comment: But I see lots of lazy loading. Is there a chance that you in some lazy loaded module you also use `<router-outlet>`, and in that module you forgot to import `RouterModule`?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you ! @JSONDerulo

Comment: Try removing router module from you app module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `RouterModule,` from your `app.module.ts` `imports` - You've got that covered in `AppRoutingModule`, which you are correctly importing in app.module.ts and I think that's the reason you're gettin that error.

`ngModel` is located in `FormsModule` - import that on relevant `*.component.ts` files

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

[...]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    [...]
    FormsModule
  ],
  [...]
})
```

Comment: still not working , after removed `RouterModule`, from my `app.module.ts` imports

Comment: Ok, the only place that should be in the imports array is on the app routing module ts file... no other files

Comment: You mean to do empty array of Import ?

Comment: No just the routing module

Answer (score 3):

for whom the first solution didn't work out, the problem might not be in the RoutingModule rather it's in some other Module that you updated,

same thing happened to me: my app.module.ts file

```
import { GalleryModule } from '@ks89/angular-modal-gallery';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    GalleryModule.forRoot()
    ...]
```

removing the `'forRoot()'` from the GalleryModule fixed my problem so it might be another module that is causing the error